# Aggregation of aggregation in Entity Framework Core 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Context: I've already implemented an ordering on some custom expression.

I have a method `GetAggregationExpression` which will return an `Expression<Func<MyEntityClass, double>>`.

This works very well for:

- Filtering
- Ordering

Now I need to implement a total.

So my idea is to reuse same expression and make a Sum (or average, depending on field).

Unfortunately, this "naive" code will throw a runtime exception:

```
var exp = GetAggregationExpression(orderData);

if (exp == null)
    continue;

var total = query.Select(exp).Sum();
```

The exception is:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I've tried multiple variations without any luck. I would like to avoid recreate a copy of `GetAggregationExpression` but for totals, as the code is almost the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you need another `Select` in between. What is the actual `exp` doing? And what is `query`?

Comment: @Charlieface So let’s say we have ObjectA which has multiple ObjectB
Exp will be like “objectA => objectA.Sum (x=>x.ObjectsB.Select(y=>y.Property))” (Might have more complex logic, but eventually it returns an expression to calculate something for every ObjectA)
The idea is to Sum these sums. The query is IQueryable< ObjectA>

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you would need another level of `SELECT` in order to aggregate an aggregation. You might be able to get this with the following

```cs
var total = query
    .Select(exp)
    .Select(total => new {total})
    .Sum(v => v.total);
```

Comment: Same error message : "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.'"

Comment: Can you show the generated SQL?

Comment: My current logger logs only "executed" SQL... I'm modifying it :)

Comment: Ok. Took a bit of diging and I simplified it as much as possible. This SQL query generates these SQL errors. SELECT COALESCE(SUM((
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM([r0].[Amount]), 0.0E0)
    FROM [RealTimesWeekEnds] AS [r0]
    WHERE [r0].[Ressource_Id] = [r].[Id])), 0.0E0)
FROM [Ressources] AS [r]
WHERE [r].[Company_Id] = 1

Comment: OK yeah that's definitely not valid, question is how to get it to generate a correctly nested query. What about `var total = query.Select(v => new { value = exp(v) })..Sum(v => v.value);` You might need to rewrite whatever `exp` is doing also, but you haven't shown that so can't advise.

Comment: That would not compile (tested) . I know I can create a copy of method wich returns exp. But the whole Idea is to have only 1 method for : Sorting (works), Filtering (works) and get totals for the same custom expression. I would love to avoid "almost" copy/oaste a method. In my head "Total of totals" makes sens :)

Comment: In theory it should work, it's just the translation isn't working correctly. I can't play with your `exp` because I don't know what type it is or how it works, but you should be able to transform it in the way I describe: to introduce another level of `SELECT` in between. Perhaps you can transform `exp` into some kind of pre-grouped join so that teh final result is something like `SELECT COALESCE(SUM(r0.Amount), 0)
FROM Ressources AS r
JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(r0.Amount), 0) AS Amount
    FROM RealTimesWeekEnds AS r0
) AS r0 ON r0.Ressource_Id = r.Id
WHERE r.Company_Id = 1`

Comment: I managed to make SQL querry work. Now just to find how to write it. SQl which works : SELECT COALESCE(SUM(r0.Amount), 0)
FROM Ressources AS r
JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(rw.Amount) AS Amount, rw.Ressource_Id
    FROM RealTimesWeekEnds AS rw
    GROUP BY rw.Ressource_Id
) AS r0
ON r0.Ressource_Id = r.Id
WHERE r.Company_Id = 1